# Local form of $p$-Laplacian operator in Riemannian manifold

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, laplacian, p-laplacian

Let $(M,g)$ be a connected oriented Riemannian manifold without boundary. The $p$-Laplacian of function $f:M\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is defined by 
$$\Delta_p f=\operatorname{div}\left(|\nabla f|^{p-2}\nabla f\right),$$ where $\nabla f$ is the gradient of $f$. I can not calculate the local form of $p$-Laplacian. I am trying to calculate it from the usual local form of laplacian operator but I am not getting any satisfactory form. Please help me.
Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by "local form"?

Comment: The local form of laplacian of $f$ can be written as $g^{ij}\partial_j\partial_i f$. I want this kind of form for the $p$-Laplacian operator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expression for the gradient vector field in local coordinates
$(x_1 , . . . , x_n )$ is
$$
\nabla_g \phi = g^{ij}\partial_i \phi,
$$
where $\partial_i \phi= \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x_i}$, and $g^{ij}$ the entries of the invese matrix of $g_{ij}$. This means
$
\nabla_g \phi = \sum_{i,j=1}^n g^{ij}\partial_i \phi \, \partial_j,
$
where $n=\dim(M)$. Then we have
$$
|\nabla_g \phi|^2= g(\nabla_g \phi,\nabla_g \phi)=g_{ij}\,  g^{hi}\, g^{kj} \, \partial_k\phi\, \partial_h \phi.
$$
On the other hand, the expression for the divergence operator is
$$
\text{div}(X)= \frac{1}{\sqrt{|\det g|}}\partial_i (\sqrt{|\det g|}\partial_i X).
$$
Combining these expressions we have
$$
\Delta_p\phi=\text{div}(|\nabla_g \phi|^{p-2}\nabla_g \phi)=
$$
$$
\frac{1}{\sqrt{|\det g|}}\sum_m\partial_m\big\{\sqrt{|\det g|}\big(\sum_{i,j,k,h}g_{ij}\,  g^{hi}\, g^{kj} \, \partial_k\phi\, \partial_h \phi\big)^{\frac{p-2}{2}}\sum_l g^{lm} \partial_l\phi\big\}.
$$